# Sql Server 2008 R2 DBCC SHRINKFILE Severe Error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dbcc

I am trying to run the following command in Sql Server 2008 R2:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename')
```

When I try to run this command, I get the following error:

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error and how to resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried specifying both the file name and the target size in MB, e.g.

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', 20);
```

Or the TRUNCATEONLY option, which doesn't try any of the nasty stuff like reorganizing all of your physical data:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('filename', TRUNCATEONLY);
```

Also you could try making sure the database is in single user mode first:

```
ALTER DATABASE db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

...and turn off any backup / log backup or other maintenance jobs that may be conflicting with your shrink operation. If it still occurs, please run a CHECKDB against this database and let us know the results:

```
DBCC CHECKDB (db) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS;
```

But just as a side note, you do know that shrinking is bad and should usually be reserved for extraordinary events and circumstances, right?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that shrinking a DB actually causes worse performance, for some reason people seem to think that a smaller database always means it will be faster to load off the disk, they ignore that it will be slower for writes and very often will be fragmented as well.

Comment: setting it to single user allowed the shrink to process...thanks!  p.s. this had to happen due to an extraordinary event, not by choice..lol

Comment: In case anybody stumbles on this, if you have a file group as read only, it may show you this error despite the fact that the file that you are trying to shrink is not in it. I suppose it is a bug.